# Modify a <p> element in a list, with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm coming back here because I'm not able to do what I want. I have a nav menu, with three 'li' in one 'ul', each containing a

element, with the nav name.
I already have a script which hides divs and show the corresponding one, containing project thumbnails. What I would like to do, is to distinguish which nav element is active, by modifying it when it has been clicked.

I gave a try to modify the string of the

element to add a dash "-" or a point • to distinguish which was the active menu but I'm not too good with jQuery yet to manipulate a "p" in a "li" in a "ul" effectively.

Here is my html :

```
<section id="content">

    <p class="section_title"> WORK </p>

    <div id="sections">
        <ul>
            <li class="section" data-grid="grid1"><p class="navigation"     style="cursor : pointer;"> Product</p></li>
            <li class="section" data-grid="grid2"><p class="navigation" style="cursor : pointer;"> Mobility</p></li>
            <li class="section" data-grid="grid3"><p class="navigation" style="cursor : pointer;"> Arcade Sticks</p></li>
            <!-- <li class="section" data-grid="grid4"><p style="cursor : pointer;">. Infography</p></li> -->
        </ul>
    </div>


<!-- PROJECT GRID -->

    <div id="project_grid">

<!-- PRODUCT PROJECTS -->

        <div id="grid1" class="grid">
            <a href="projects/product/jorislaarman.html" style="background:url('assets/img/thumbnails/jorislaarman.png')"></a>
            <a href="projects/product/ptitlouis.html" style="background:url('assets/img/thumbnails/ptitlouis.png')"></a>
            <a href="projects/product/diwel.html" style="background:url('assets/img/thumbnails/diwel.png')"></a>
            <a href="projects/product/wirquin.html" style="background:url('assets/img/thumbnails/wirquin.png')"></a>
            <a href="projects/product/ulna.html" style="background:url('assets/img/thumbnails/ulna.png')"></a>
            <a href="projects/product/envol.html" style="background:url('assets/img/thumbnails/envol.png')"></a>
        </div>
```

There are other grids following, each manipulated by the jQuery, here :

```
$("#project_grid div:not(#grid1)").hide();

$('.section').click(function() {
    $('.grid').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).data('grid')).show();
});
```

I tried several things with the jQuery there, without alterating the original script, to at least underline the clicked

element, such as :

```
$('.navigation').click(function(){
$('p').css("text-decoration","underlined");
});
```

and :

```
$('p').clicked(function(){
    $(this).css('text-decoration','underlined');
});
```

But none of this works :/ And I can't really figure it out.

I also tried to modify the

string, with .append, but I couldn't figure it out ether...

I'd just like to do something simple. Either underline the active nav section, either add a "•" before product, mobility, or arcade stick section when they have been clicked. And of course disappear when another one is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/g32Vm/

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of modifying CSS properties, the simpler solution is $(this). $(this) refers to target/active element on which the event was performed.

```
$('.navigation').click(function(){
 $(this).css('text-decoration','underline');
});
```

Secondly, it should be "underline" instead of "underlined" 
You can also try adding/removing temporary classes to the active element to distinguish it from other elements.

Answer (score 0):

oh thanks Kamlesh Kushwaha. It worked, though the underline wasn't going away. But anyway, I got a bit more the "this" property. and I made this with the original script :

```
$("#project_grid div:not(#grid1)").hide();
$("#point3,#point2").hide();

$('.section').click(function() {
    $('.grid').hide();
    $('.point').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).data('grid')).show();
    $('#' + $(this).data('point')).show();
});
```

And I added this before each of my nav sections :

```
<p id="point1" class="point">•</p>
<p id="point2" class="point">•</p>
<p id="point3" class="point">•</p>
```

Here is the JS : http://jsfiddle.net/g32Vm/5/

NOTA : Just in case a rookie like me ends up here and wants to do a similar sthing with

elements, don't forget to add "display : inline" as a css value to avoid having a new line created with each

tag.

Thanks for the help :) I'm kinda starting to enjoy jQuery :D